# do a sum for each entry in table

Tags: mysql, sum

i got two tables a and b
table a contains some names like cobol, php, cmd and a refnumber

```
name ref
Cobol 1
php   2
cmd   3
...
```

table b contains multiple projekts where i used one of table a
like year, mm, and a reference to table a
that means f.e

```
year mm ref
1982 8  1
1982 4  2
1983 5  3
1983 1  1
1982 6  3
1994 12 1
1995 12 2
1996 6  1
1996 6  2
```

now i want to know how many month in total (from b) i used one of table a to get a list like

```
Cobol 27
php   20
cmd   11
```

Note :sums might be not corret in this example.

An answer provided below made me realize I need to clarify the situation further.

Table a has the ref in a so far not mentioned table c with the content:

```
id number uses 
1   1      1
2   1      2
3   2      1
4   2      3
5   2      4
```

So table a (pgojekt) contains each project I've worked on and each entry there has a year and number of month in it. It references an other table for example reflanguages.  In Languages there are the possible languages while reflanguages contains the reference to the language.

I hope this is understandable.

For example in 1982 i did 2 projects (1 and 2)  each with 6 month duration. While Project 1 uses languages 1 and 2, project 2 uses language 3 and 4. In 1983, I did another 12 month project that uses languages 1 and 2 and in 1984 one with 3 month 1 and 2 and one with 4 and 5 and 6.

Now the problem seems that a `select name, sum(mm)` as you suggested shows all but not the sum for Cobol in all those years, followed by php in all those years, followed by....

if this gets to complicated i can add a db dump.

what i want is a list like written above.

I got it working when specifying the name in a where clause, however I want it for all names in table a as shown above

How can this be achieved with MySQL?

Comment: Hi @Rolf - please take the time to view the [tour] and read the help center.  When you need to add details in response to comments asking for clarification, or an answer, please hit the [edit] link below the question and add those details to your question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following (untested) should do what you want:

```
select name, sum(mm)
from a join b using (ref)
group by name;
```